# Returning data from a sub-class

Tags: java, inheritance, return, superclass, super

I have a subclass "shopStaff" within class "staff". I have a meathod getPerson which I need to send the data set in staff and the data set in shopStaff as a single string.

This is my code

// in staff

```
public String getPerson()
{
    return format(name) + format(yearJoined);
}
```

// in shopStaff

```
public String getPerson()
{
    super.getPerson();
    return format(department);
}
```

however, when I invoke the getPerson meathod in the subclass it only returns the department information, not the name and yearjoined (that I only set in the superclass.

I thought when I used the super. meathod it would return everything from the class above in the hierarchy. Is this not the case? If not could anyone tell me how I access the information set in the superclass?

Thanks

CJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call:

```
super.getPerson();
```

The return is discarded as it is not stored anywhere. You'd want to do this:

```
//in shopStaff
public String getPerson() {
  return super.getPerson() + format(department);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your return value from `super.getPerson()` is not returned with the `return` statement in your current `getPerson()` method. It is just lost in your code.

You need to change your `shopStaff` method to return the super class values with your subclass return statement: -

```
public String getPerson()
{
    return super.getPerson() + format(department);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getPerson()
{
    String fromSuper=super.getPerson();
    return fromSuper + format(department);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calling super will not get data unless you read and use it in subclass.

May be something like this will work:

```
public String getPerson()
{
    String person = super.getPerson();
    return person+format(department);
}
```